# Populating a text box with the results of a calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form where a user enters price and quantity, soon after the mouse leaves the 'Quantity' text box, I want the TotalPrice text box to be populated with result of Price * Quantity. The following is my jQuery code, however the TotalPrice text box does not get populated with the result. Hope someone can advise me on how to go about getting it right.

```
$("#quantity").mouseleave (function () {
    var i = $("#price").val();
    var k = $("#quantity").val();
    var total = i*k;
    $("#totalprice").val(total);
});
```

Comment: show all relevant code in OP .. js and html

Comment: You need to wrap the same code in `blur` event handler of those two textboxes. To bind the event use `$('selector1, selector2').blur(function() { // Same code here });`.

Comment: I think you should create a fiddle for this.

Comment: Just a point to consider, don't get too caught up on the mouse leaving as a user may use tab to exit the field or be on a touch device/screen.   Therefore check for when the field looses focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `blur` event handler of those two textboxes. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#price").on("blur", calculate);
  $("#quantity").on("blur", calculate);
  //If you want to do the calculation when the page renders:
  calculate();
});

function calculate(){
  var i = $("#price").val();
  var k = $("#quantity").val();
  var total = i*k;    
  $("#totalprice").val(total);                
}
```

As trincot mentioned in the comment below, you can merge the two events in one line since they call the same function:

```
$("#price, #quantity").on("blur", calculate);
```

Comment: Is it not better to check both fields have values? Otherwise results would be inaccurate

Comment: @Tushar That's only required if the two fields have values when the page renders. I will add it with a comment.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Sure, but validation was not part of the question.

Comment: Or:  `$("#price, #quantity").on("blur", calculate);`

Comment: @trincot I always prefer them separate, but I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @RacilHilan Thank you, I found your suggestion works best for me, appreciate it.Thanks everyone for your suggestions too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it is getting executed ONLY ONCE as soon as the `ready` function is called.
You need to attach a listner to the action element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quantity").mouseleave(function(){
        var i = $("#price").val();
        var k = $("#quantity").val();
        var total = i*k;    
        $("#totalprice").val(total);  
    });         
});
```

You can use various event listners such as onchange, onfocusout, blur, onkeyup depending on how and when you want the changes to happen. For more info on types of events and all for jquery only - https://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: I don't have a mouse. I use TAB key to move around.

Comment: There are various events you can use. E.g:- onchange, onfocusout, blur. Just figure out which event suits your needs. You can even use onkeyup() event to do a realtime execution

Comment: This should work if you change mouseleave with focusout

Comment: Downvoter, could you please let me know the reason so I could improve my code for the same?

Comment: The downvotes reason is obvious from the comments to your answer. Note: I'm not a downvoter.

Comment: @RacilHilan which is what? Because I used mouseleave event listner? The OP asked it on mouse leave event so I simply added that specific event listner. I also added in the comments other types of event listners. Not being rude here, what may be obvious to you might not be obvious to me.

Comment: Yes, that was the obvious reason. Somebody obviously upvoted the first comment by OP and downvoted your answer. I'm not saying I agree with that, I'm only telling you the obvious. Again, I'm not the downvoter and I agree with what you said.

Comment: @RacilHilan relax. I am not blaming you for anything. But thanks for helping out

Comment: :-) I know, no problem. I hate the downvoting feature and I think SO should make leaving a comment mandatory when downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var price = $("#price");
    var qty = $("#quantity");
    var total = $("#totalprice");
    /* CREATE VARIABLES ON DOCUMENT READY, 
       BECAUSE YOU WANT TO CACHE THE DOM SELECTION */
    qty.on("blur", function(){
         var i = price.val();
         var k = qty.val();
         total.val(i * k);
    });
});
```

working fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/tonysamperi/xqxm3900/

Comment: Tony. Just wondering, why would you load the the whole dom at the start instead of just loading the values inside the function?

Comment: It's written in the commment

Comment: Why are you shouting in the comment?

Comment: I'm not shouting, it's just to highlight

Comment: Also...the "shouting" thing is just a forum thing...It doesn't apply to any text on the web.

Comment: But what's the difference between caching vs getting the value within the function? wouldn't caching actually slow down the comp? (Not related to the op's question. just curious as to why apply this method)

Comment: Since on every blur he needs to read values from the input it's better this way. It's a bit slower on init, but it's a way faster for the next calculations.